# stripe.customers.retreiveSource Receiving Empty Array in data instead of card objects

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

As you can see in my dashboard I have three cards but I am getting an empty array in data. Everything else is perfect. I am following the stripe documentation.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dashboard now adds cards as [Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods) for customers instead of Sources.

Try [retrieving the Payment Methods](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list?lang=node) for that customer instead:

```
const pms = await stripe.paymentMethods.list(
  {customer: 'cus_123', type: 'card'}
);
```